# Is there a word to describe the act of portraying words from one language using just the looks of characters of another?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, "卄モㄥㄥ口" may look like "Hello" to English readers, but these Chinese letters do not mean anything relevant when translated. Is there a word to describe the way this is illustrated?

Comment: It's kind of the opposite of an [informal romanisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informal_romanizations_of_Cyrillic) where you represent non-Roman text in Roman/ASCII characters, for instance you write "CoBeTcKuu' CoIO3" instead of "Советский Союз". An *informal transliteration*, maybe? Or *faux-Chinese* by analogy with [Faux-Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/faux_Cyrillic)? But ELU isn't the place for making up words/terminology.

Comment: This looks to be the same as what a schoolboy does when he keys the number **58008** into his calculator, then proudly shows it upside-down to his mates as spelling out the word **BOOBS** (twee slang for "tits / breasts"). Is it really worthy of a dedicated name?

Comment: Not a single word, buy you can say that such words are written or "illustrated" with what is called a **foreign imitation typeface** ([Ex. 1](https://www.1001fonts.com/foreign-imitation-fonts.html), [Ex. 2](https://www.fontget.com/discover/foreign-imitation/)). The purpose is to **evoke** the words, language, or culture of the imitated alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be called "*character replacement*" or "*use of homoglyphs*"

Characters and symbols which look similar can be called [homoglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph).

Such misuse of Cyrillic is common and is called [faux Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faux_Cyrillic). You could call your example *"faux Chinese characters"* or "*faux Latin characters*" depending on which side you view it from.

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say all examples are necessarily "misuse." You arrive at an airport in a foreign country and you see a sign saying "Welcome to X" written in English with a font imitating their alphabet, would you say they are misusing the font? The same for an ad to visit a country or the word "Menu" written in imitation Chinese font on a Chinese Restaurant's menu.

Comment: Is it's a bespoke font that has visual elements similar to the local script, it's not misuse as it's not the local script. If you use the actual glyphs of the local language, and they don't represent the sound or idea it's used for in the English sign, it's very much misuse.

Comment: Great answer! Homoglyphic is probably the best word for this. Thanks! Interesting point about faux Cyrillic too.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a word to describe the way this is illustrated?

I can only think of the informal to "Chinese-ify the word". The "-[i]fy" suffix is still productive in English.

"adjective[i]fy" = to make or cause to be in the manner of the adjective.

OED

> They [=words with the suffix "[i]fy] may be divided into three classes (corresponding to three classes of adjectives in -ficus: see -fic suffix), all of which are represented by adapted words in English: (2) < adjectives, with the sense ‘to bring into a certain state’, as santificāre sanctify;

It is worth noting that there seems to be no general term - each style must be identified, e.g. Frenchify; Russify, and they are not regular.